# "git push origin master" gives weird behavior in bash script

Tags: bash, git

I have this simple function in my bashrc file

```sh
function aupgrade {
    cat ~/.bash_aliases > ~/bash/.bash_aliases
    cd ~/bash
    git add .

    if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
        git commit -m "Update"
    else
        git commit -m "$1"
    fi

    git push origin master

    cd - 1>/dev/null
}
```

> This function has a purpose, this is the expected behavior:

**First**, replace the content of the .bash_aliases file in the bash repository with the stdout of `cat ~/.bash_aliases`

**Second**, go into the `~/bash` directory which is a git respository

**Third**, stage all changes

**Fourth**, if when calling the `aupgrade` function the following argument is nothing, just commit with the "Update" message, but if the user wrote an argument, like `aupgrade "New commit!"`, commit the changes with such argument as the message, `git commit -m $1`

**Fifth**, push the changes

**Sixth**, go back to the previous directory

> BUT, it doesnt do that, instead it just does:

**First**, replace the content of the .bash_aliases file in the bash repository with the stdout of `cat ~/.bash_aliases`

**Second**, go into the `~/bash` directory which is a git respository

**Third**, stage all changes

**Fourth**, commit with the "Update" message although there is an argument

**Fifth**, push the changes

**Sixth**, go back to the previous directory

This is weird. This looks product of the `git push origin master` line. It's not a conditional problem, because when I wrote another function like this but without the `git push origin master` line it worked as desired.

Why does this happen? Is there any solution?

This is what set -x shows to me, it's really weird
[image: set -x's output]

Comment: Can I recommend to simplify `if`? Use `git commit -m "${1:-Update}"` instead.

Comment: Does changing this `if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then` to `if [[ "$1" == "" ]]; then` help ? This is based on [shellcheck's](https://www.shellcheck.net/) suggestions : __Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting__.

Comment: Generally useful trick for debugging shell scripts and functions: `set -x`. Now the shell prints (to the shell's stderr) each command as it executes it. (`set +x` to clear the flag.)

Comment: To dear Saurabh: No, sorry :p doesn't change anything, I appreciate the tip though!

Comment: To dear phd: hmmm works the same, but I appreciate the trick!! Thank you very much!

Comment: The output is quite interesting: it seems your function ran, and then the argument to it was evaluated as a separate second command, as if you'd entered `aupgrade; "Heeellloset -x"` as two separate commands on one line. That's not supposed to happen, as far as I know, but there could be some dark bash corner where you can mark functions as "this function takes no arguments", perhaps.

Comment: `!!` is being expanded to `set -x` via history expansion, since it's in double quotes and this is an interactive shell.

Comment: @MartínNieva, the error you have from git is not about whether the program is called from a script, it's about whether the commit you're trying to push is a child of the current remote head. That error is completely normal when you need to either merge or rebase on top of the remote master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have tested your code, and the only problem I could find is that passing your first argument as a string with multiple exclamation marks inserts the same (or previous?) command unless you escape it:

[image]

It looks like this is exactly what happened for you, but you had "set -x" ran beforehand, thus it replaced the double exclamation marks with that command.

I'd also recommend storing function arguments in named local variables for cleaner code.